# Copy a value from an array to struct's variables

Tags: arrays, c, struct, strtok

Is there any way to copy a value from one array to a struct variable? Here is an example:

I have a struct and the struct has these variables;

```
struct example
{ 
    int a;
    char b[];
};
```

and I have an array that name is "token" in my main function. (First, in an another function, I used strtok to divide my string into tokens, and then I used that token array in my main function).

Now my token array is like:

```
token[0] = abc;
token[1] = 2;
token[2] = 10;
```

Now my aim is to match these token's values into my struct's variables.

Like;

if token [0] == "something" (it should be string)
then do int a = 3

if token [0] =="anotherthing" (it should be string)
then do int a=2

and

token[1] =b;(I want to give token[1] value into the b array)

How can I do that? Are there any suggestions?

Comment: I can't make sense of this.

Comment: what do you mean by `symbol`?  are you trying to update `int` value based on `strcmp`? its not entirely clear what you are trying. A minimal code  should be good

Comment: updated. more info added. @IrAM

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to copy a value from one array to a struct variable?

A C array is a series of consecutive values all of the same type. It could be a series of structs, or ints, or characters... any valid type. If you copy one or more of those values, you can of course do what you like with them, including assigning them to parts of a structure. If you have:

```
int intArray[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

and a struct:

```
struct Example
{
    int start1; 
    int end1;
    int start2; 
    int end2;
    char symbol[];
};

struct Example ex;
```

then you can assign values from the array to parts of an instance of that struct just as you'd make any other assignment:

```
ex.start1 = intArray[0];
ex.end1 = intArray[4];
ex.start2 = intArray[1];
ex.end2 = intArray[3];
```

Parts of your example are confusing because it's not clear that the values in your array are the same:

```
token[0] = abc;
token[1] = 2;
token[2] = 10;
```

What is `abc` here? If it's an `int` like the other values, that's fine, but what it is and how it relates to the other values isn't clear. Some other languages allow different types of values in the same array, but that's not the case with C.

Comment: abc is a string value by the way. Because the first token is a string. but the others are int yes.

Comment: @Fenikssy That's the confusing part; C doesn't allow you to mix strings and ints in the same array, so you need to think about what you're trying to do. How is `token` declared? I understand that it's an array, but an array of what type?